# nav bouncing when transform a div on hover

Tags: html, css

I'm building a navigation for my site. I use flexbox for this one. I'd like to show a bar on the bottom of `.nav-item` when it's hovered. The span should be centered verticaly in the `nav` and the `.bar` *should always be on the bottom* of `nav` and `.nav-item.` To get this layout I have another `.bar` above the text, which has `background-color: transparent;`. Than I use flexbox and `justify-content: space-between;`, to get my layout (span center vertical and `.bar` on bottom when hover). At the moment this works fine. There are some points I'd like to change, but I havn't god an idea how:

- When hover on `.nav-item`, the `.bar` should transform it's height, without bouncing the `nav` (look at the snippet). The `nav` should stay and just the `.bar` should come up and down.
- I'd like to put some `padding` on my nav, but when I do this, the layout is wrong (bar is not on bottom of nav, it's clear why). How to solve this (having padding on nav and still get the correct layout)?
- Is there another (perhaps bether way) to put the bar on bottom, to center the span vertical without my hidden bar?

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  /*padding: 20px;*/
  border-bottom: 1px solid lightgrey;
}

.nav-item {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-right: 20px;
  height: 100%;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  cursor: pointer;
  /*padding: 20px;*/
}

.bar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 0px;
  background-color: blue;
  transition: height 200ms ease-in-out;
}

.hidden {
  background-color: transparent;
}

.nav-item:hover>.bar {
  height: 3px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="nav-item">
    <div class="bar hidden"></div>
    <span>Item 1</span>
    <div class="bar"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="nav-item">
    <div class="bar hidden"></div>
    <span>Item 2</span>
    <div class="bar"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="nav-item">
    <div class="bar hidden"></div>
    <span>Item 3</span>
    <div class="bar"></div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because of the expanding new `height`. To make in your way, you need to use `position` and get the bar out of the layout:

```css
nav {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  /*padding: 20px;*/
  border-bottom: 1px solid lightgrey;
  min-height: 27px;                           /* This one */
}
```

**Snippet**

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  /*padding: 20px;*/
  border-bottom: 1px solid lightgrey;
}

.nav-item {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-right: 20px;
  height: 100%;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  cursor: pointer;
  /*padding: 20px;*/
  position: relative;
}

.bar {
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 0px;
  background-color: blue;
  transition: height 200ms ease-in-out;
  position: absolute;
}

.hidden {
  background-color: transparent;
}

.nav-item:hover>.bar {
  height: 3px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="nav-item">
    <div class="bar hidden"></div>
    <span>Item 1</span>
    <div class="bar"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="nav-item">
    <div class="bar hidden"></div>
    <span>Item 2</span>
    <div class="bar"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="nav-item">
    <div class="bar hidden"></div>
    <span>Item 3</span>
    <div class="bar"></div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: The bar isn't on the bottom at the moment with your solution. It should be still on bottom (so there shouldn't be a space between the gray border and the blue bar like in this snippet).

Comment: @MrBuggy I don't understand. Can you please clarify once again?

Comment: @MrBuggy I got it.

Comment: You can compare the blue bar in my snippet and in yours. In yours there is a space between the blue bar and the grey border (so it's not on the bottom). In my snippet there is no space (blue bar lies on grey border). This is the layout I'd like to have.

Comment: @MrBuggy Check now please. Refresh.

Comment: Now the blue bar is under the grey border? It should be like in my snippet, above the grey border lying on the border...

Comment: @MrBuggy That's simple. Give me another few seconds... `:)`

Comment: @MrBuggy Check now?

Comment: Now it's perfect, I edited your answer putting some padding on .nav-item to solve my second point in the question. Have you got an idea for my third point or is this a good way to solve it for this kind of layout? Cheers

Comment: @MrBuggy I'll get you another way.

Answer (score 1):

Try this CSS

```
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  /*padding: 20px;*/
  border-bottom: 1px solid lightgrey;
}

.nav-item {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-right: 20px;
  height: 100%;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  padding:10px;
  /*padding: 20px;*/
}

.bar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: blue;
  bottom:0px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin:auto;
  transition: height 200ms ease-in-out;
}

.hidden {
  background-color: transparent;
}

.nav-item:hover>.bar {
  height: 3px;

}
```

hope this helps..